# How do I update the application from within the application?

Tags: android

How can make an update inside the application? Instagram updated from the application.

**Device :** Google Pixel XL (Android 7.1 Nougat)

Like this;

**NOTE : Screenshot language Turkish**

[image][image][image]

Comment: Prolly because instagram app is not native ... for native apps mostly on non rooted devices it is not possible (ok we have DexClassLoader, but you cannot add new Activity nor Service nor even xml layout using it without installing new version of apk)

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "make an update inside the application?" means.

Comment: I want to update in application. Without Google Play Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google Play [Developer Content Policy](http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html), an app downloaded from Google Play is not allowed to update itself in any other way than through Google Play. However, technically some degree of self-updating functionality is achievable by eg. reflection and dynamic classloading. [Evolve](https://blog.vivekpanyam.com/evolve-seamlessly-deploy-android-apps-to-users) can serve as a proof of concept, although it seems to be abandoned.